# DirectAdmin, Multple PHP Versions and MSSQL

Tags: php, directadmin, php-mssql

In the past I have setup connections to MSSQL by using the MSSQL functions.  I have an old site (client is refusing to upgrade) that runs php 5.5, sadly the functions have gone missing (it was working but now isn't)

I've tried to re-install using the script below but still cannot get the module to show when doing `php -m`

```
Download FreeTDS
Latest stable version can be found here http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/ALPHA/freetds/stable/ (

3. Configure and install FreeTDS
Uncompress and cd to the respective folder:

./configure --prefix=/usr/local/freetds
make
make install

4. PHP configuration
Edit the php configuration file.
"/usr/local/directadmin/custombuild/configure/ap2/configure.php55" 
Add this line: "--with mssql=/usr/local/freetds\ " 

Go to custombuild:
./build clean
./build php_expert 5.5 php-fpm
```

Again when I do `php - m` the module doesn't show

```
[root@... domains]# php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]

[root@... domains]#
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are trying to connect to MS SQL Server using MSSQL PHP extension (mssql_ functions), but this extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 and removed in PHP 7.0.0.

Comment: @Zhorov did you meant php 5.5 or php 5.3 in your comment?  if 5.3 this is 5.5

Comment: I mean PHP 5.3. And I'm sure that `mssql` extension is not available anymore on **Windows** starting from PHP 5.3 and removed in PHP 7.0.0. I'm not sure about the **Linux** platform. An alternative for this extension is PHP Driver for SQL Server (`PDO` or `sqlsrv_` functions), but you need to rewrite the code.

Comment: @Zhorov this was orignally working in php 5.6 but for whatever reason that version of php (and version 8) have become corrupt and won't recompile :(  I've updated the code to just do shell calls to TSQL part of freetds for now

Answer (score 0):

I remember when the `mssql` functions died. It was a sad day, and caused me a lot of headaches.

I found that the easiest conversion was to move to the `sqlsrv` functions. They are nearly identical in their syntax and structure, with only a couple of adjustments necessary. Luckily, doing a file-wide search from your IDE should make it fairly easy to locate any `mssql` commands, and "convert" them in-place.

The connection function is a bit different as it uses an array of arguments to specify the database, username, password, etc., but these are well-documented and you only need to change them where you're making that connection (which is often only coded in one place). But most of the operation functions are essentially the same.

One thing to note is that `sqlsrv` is more pointer-related than `mssql` was. You can either adjust to advance through the records with the provided functions (and their examples on php.net) **or** you can continue to use the standard structure (the while loop method) if you just add the `SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC` constant as the second argument of `sqlsrv_fetch_array`. This will cause it to simulate the old behavior, and eliminate the need for using the pointer-related functions.

```
$connection = sqlsrv_connect( $server, $connection_info_array );
$results = sqlsrv_query( $connection , $your_query );
while ( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $results, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {
var_dump( $row );
}
```

This greatly simplified the task when I converted my own code. Later, I rebuilt my database classes to use `PDO`, but the interim move to `sqlsrv` saved a great deal of time I didn't have right then.

Comment: Doesn't this still require the libraries to be installed and working?